# Resize videos in android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, resize, mediastore

I'm looking to resize videos captured using the MediaStore Intent after they have been saved to the SD card.  I've done similar things with c# and ffmpeg and thought about using that with android but I've yet to be able to find a way to incorporate that into my eclipse running on my windows 7 machine.

I'm a total *nix noob so all of the solutions that I've found for building ffmpeg into an android app are completely greek to me.

Is there an alternative solution to ffmpeg that perhaps is already built into the android sdk for resizing videos?

I'm just looking for the path of least resistance here...

Answer (score 3):

**No**, there is no api in android, to resize the video you have in sdcard. Because resizing video means you are manipulating the video, which is a complex task and no android api is currently available to do that task.

So you just have to make use of external lib. like `ffmpeg` and make `*.so` of it for using it in android. You can have a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20991431/3098658) to have a help for making `*.so` files.

Hope this helps. Cheers. :)

Comment: Now there is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842668/how-to-compress-mp4-video-using-mediacodec-android/33313421#33313421