# How to compress mp4 video using MediaCodec Android?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

In my Android app, I want to compress mp4 video by changing its resolution, bitrate. I don't want to use FFmpeg (because I don't want to use NDK), so I decided to use MediaCodec API.

Here are my logical steps:

1. Extract video file with MediaExtractor, then decode data.
2. Create new encoder with my new resolution, bitrate and encode data.
3. Using MediaMuxer to create a new mp4 file.

My problem is: I don't know how to setup the connection between output of decoder and input of encoder. I can decode the video to a Surface or encode a new video from a surface. But I don't understand how to connect them.

I read these links: [Android MediaCodec: Reduce mp4 video size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076742/android-mediacodec-reduce-mp4-video-size), [Video compression on android using new MediaCodec Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950610/video-compression-on-android-using-new-mediacodec-library) and the example from Bigflake: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/DecodeEditEncodeTest.java

Can anybody give me a clear explanation what I have to do?

Comment: To do a straight copy, you would just get the input surface from the encoder (via `getInputSurface()`) and pass that to the decoder as the output surface (via `configure()`).

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796711/fast-video-compression-like-whatsapp/31823187#31823187

Comment: The MediaCodec API is quite obscure and undocumented. I've started a bounty on this question. Hopelly someone will publish a class they already have.
Big mp4 file on disk -> Small mp4 file on disk. All using MediaCodec.
That would save countless lives ! (well, maybe not, but sure would save mine ^^)

Comment: @TOP i am using the below answer's to compressor library to compress the video file..But i am not getting the audio from it..Could u please help me to short out from this problem

Comment: Can you please share a sample of how you finally did that? Thank you

Answer (score 18):

I have used this to see how to manipulate video in android: https://github.com/hoolrory/AndroidVideoSamples , check the [`VideoResampler.java`](https://github.com/hoolrory/AndroidVideoSamples/blob/master/CommonVideoLibrary/src/com/roryhool/commonvideolibrary/VideoResampler.java) in the `CommonVideoLibrary` .

Comment: Sample use : 

VideoResampler resampler = new VideoResampler();

resampler.addSamplerClip( new SamplerClip( inputUri ) );

resampler.setOutput( outputUri );

resampler.setOutputResolution( Resolution.RESOLUTION_720P.getWidth(), Resolution.RESOLUTION_720P.getHeight() );

           try {
              resampler.start();
           } catch ( Throwable e ) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }

It works like magic !!

Comment: @Taiko No audio after compressing it. Is there any code missing?

Comment: @SkyWalker Sorry. In my case I only used video. Feel free to update my post with audio as well !

Comment: @SkyWalker a bit late, but check this answer https://github.com/hoolrory/AndroidVideoSamples/issues/1#issuecomment-256654251 `mux` function adds the audio track, I tried it and worked with me