# How to stream video from android camera using RTSP?

Tags: java, android, rtsp

I have to build an android app that can stream video from phone to server using RTSP. What is the best method to implement this?

Comment: Vlc media player,exo player....

Comment: @ShivamOberoi actually I want to stream live video from the camera to server, not to play video on phone

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36294158/what-is-a-faster-way-of-uploading-video-to-server-using-android-app check this

Comment: @ShivamOberoi thank you. But this says about uploading a video after saving it. what i need is live streaming directly from camera.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Streaming video from Android camera to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550847/streaming-video-from-android-camera-to-server)